# How to restore correct menu images?

Tags: macos, restore, graphics

I hate to post a screenshot, but I don't know how to describe this:

http://cl.ly/image/3l411o321G2f/mail.png

Yep. That's Mail.app, and all of my other apps have similar behavior. It started after I installed [this](http://k-profiler.deviantart.com/art/Black-Dock-for-Mountain-Lion-385086213) package.

I've tried the instructions provided at that link to uninstall it, but it didn't help. Any tips on how to restore it manually without restoring the entire system? I'm on Mavericks.

Comment: You might hate to post a screenshot, but this helps a lot to make the question clear. Welcome to AskDifferent!

Did you create a backup as stated here? /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app

Comment: I did make a backup. Restoring it only affected the dock. Strangely, the package seemed to change more than just the dock.